# What does "--remote" actually do in "git submodule update --remote"?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I just do not understand the help page of Git. So what does happen or what is the difference?

Assume I have a Git project A with a submodule B. Submodule B does have a submodule C. After cloning the repository A points to a specific commit of B. And B points to a specific commit of C.

If I am inside A I go to B by

```
cd B
```

Now I type

```
git submodule update --remote
```

or

```
git submodule update
```

What is the difference? Assuming that the remote server does have changes in A, B and C.

I *guess* that using "git submodule update --remote" keeps the reference to the specific version of C. Does using it without `--remote` update to the latest version of C?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose B is the only submodule of A.

```
cd A
git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep commit
```

The output is something like

`160000 commit 0814c6ba8f45829f04709c56118868d2483444c2 foo`

`foo` is the submodule folder and `0814c6ba8f45829f04709c56118868d2483444c2` is its revision tracked by A's current commit.

`git submodule update` does something like

```
cd B
git checkout 0814c6ba8f45829f04709c56118868d2483444c2
```

`git submodule update --remote` is like

```
cd B
git fetch origin master
git checkout origin/master
```

By default `master` and `origin/master` are used. If the branch is specified by `submodule.foo.branch = bar` in `.gitmodule`, then`bar` and `origin/bar` are used.

Comment: quite a newb in Git, can I assume "git submodule update" should never be used, since we always want the latest version of the sub module

Comment: @RichardFu It depends. In some cases you may need the latest revision and in others you may not.

Comment: Could you give a reference? This info is not in `git help submodule`.

Comment: @CédricVanRompay See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---remote and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---branchltbranchgt

Comment: you might want to keep the `--remote` for release pipelines so you always fetch latest changes of some other repo, but avoid it for feature development as you might want to manually choose which commit to use

Answer (score 1):

`git submodule update --remote`

allows you to use the submodule’s remote-tracking branch instead of the specific commit (aka. SHA) recorded in the supermodule.

`git submodule update`

allows you to use specific commit recorded in the supermodule.